# Ionic QR scanner camera works only once after installing app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I've implemented ionic cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-qrscanner` in my app. The problem I'm having is it only works once when installing the app, and any subsequent launches give me a blank black screen instead of the camera preview. First time it works perfectly, but when I close the app and open it again, a black screen is shown (due to me setting the opacity of the app to 0 so the camera preview can be shown). Only way to get the camera to show again is **clearing app data** and launching it again. I've been trying to fix this behavior for quite some time now and I can't seem to find anything that can give me insight on this problem.

Is there something the plugin or the app itself can do to cause all subsequent camera previews to fail?

This is the main part that launches the camera preview:

```
if (this.cameraFormDisabled) {
  return;
}

this.blockBackButton = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
  if (this.cameraScanning) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = "1";
    this.cameraFormDisabled = false;
    this.cameraScanning = false;
    this.qrScanner.destroy();

    this.qrScan.unsubscribe();
  } else {
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
});

this.cameraFormDisabled = true;

this.qrScanner.prepare()
.then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
  if (status.authorized) {
    this.cameraScanning = true;
    this.qrScanner.show();
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = "0";
    this.qrScan = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe(async (text: string) => {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = "1";
      this.doorLicence = text;

      this.cameraFormDisabled = false;
      this.cameraScanning = false;

      await this.qrScan.unsubscribe(); // stop cameraScanning
      await this.qrScanner.hide(); // hide camera preview
      await this.qrScanner.destroy();

      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

      this.validateLicence();
    });
  } else if (status.denied) {  // izgleda da ovde ne moze da udje jer ako je status denied, onda ide u catch
    // camera permission was permanently denied
    // you must use QRScanner.openSettings() method to guide the user to the settings page
    // then they can grant the permission from there
    this.cameraFormDisabled = false;
  } else {  // izgleda da ovde ne moze da udje jer ako je status denied, onda ide u catch
    // permission was denied, but not permanently. You can ask for permission again at a later time.
    this.cameraFormDisabled = false;
    this.presentCameraPermissionDeniedModal();
  }
})
.catch((e: any) => {
  console.log('Error is', e);
  if (e.name == "CAMERA_ACCESS_DENIED") {
    this.presentCameraPermissionDeniedModal();
  }

  this.cameraFormDisabled = false;
})
.finally(() => {
});
```

First part of the code is to make the hardware back button exit the camera preview, and second part is taken from the plugin documentation. To enable camera preview (or rather show the camera preview itself) i set the opacity of the body to 0.

The code itself should be fine, I'm interested in what can cause a permanent change of this behavior when the app is closed.

Comment: Are those "// izgleda da ovde ne moze..." ("seems like it cannot enter here...") comments tested with alerts or it just *seems* it's not entering there? Have you tested with a connected device or installed on other device? In short, I'd put lots of alerts to see which vars have which values at all points, and which conditions are triggered.

Comment: Yes, those cases have been thoroughly tested. The reason the program can't enter there is because I have a seperate permission handler, so those cases are not used anymore, I haven't removed them only as a precaution, but so far the QR scanner is actually working, only problem is the camera preview doesn't work (I can still scan the code with a black screen). This question is more about possible reasons the camera preview stops working when app is launched once, something gets written in memory and the preview won't show until the data has been cleared.

Comment: So you actually don't get errors? Have you tried both on Android and iOS, and different models? For example, I know that MIUI (Xiaomi's) does have some issues with camera previews. Also, what Android SDK are you targetting - have you tried both on Android 9 and 11? It might not be about your code's logic.

Comment: Nope, no errors thrown. I'm currently only testing on Android so I haven't tried iOS. I've tested it on Android 10. Target sdk is 28, I have tried others as well, same behavior. It's worth noting the camera used to work, but suddenly stopped, no changes made have been in any way related to the camera. There have been many other changes, but I don't know what caused it. I was hoping to get some insight on what could be possibly be causing it, or simply what CAN cause something like this.